# Charged for Publishing Azure Functions from VisualStudio?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, cost-management

Do you get billed in Azure for each time you publish an Azure Functions from VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes, you get charged *for* publishing an Azure Function from Visual Studio**. But **"each time?"** well, not really.

So, let's get to understand how that works. Azure functions although they offer you 1,000,000 executions per month (considering the execution time and memory), your code has to live somewhere which is the Function Storage Account.

Storage Accounts pricing could be broken down into two main costs:

1. Storage:
   You pay for storage per month (pay-as-you-go) unless you are on a Premium storage plan. The first 50 TB of data in a Hot access tier of blob data is ~$0.0184 to $0.0424 per GB depends on where your data is hosted and its redundancy.

*Now in your case that cost will incure once per 50 TB per month*

2. Transfer:
   When you deploy your data via Visual Studio you're effectively making API calls to Write your data which is charged (also depends on your data host location and redundancy) per 10,000 operations that includes every time you or your function does PutBlob, PutBlock, PutBlockList, AppendBlock, SnapshotBlob, CopyBlob, and SetBlobTier on that Storage Account. The operations cost varies from $0.05 to $0.091 for every 10,000 operations.
3. Others:
   Other costs may incure using features such as Blob Index, Blob Changes, and encryption.

#### Conclusion

Publishing your Function from Visual Studio contributes to the overall cost of the Functions's Storage Accout. However, the cost is very small (sub $1) even if you published your function thousands of times every month.

For more information about Azure Blob Storage pricing visit https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/#pricing